# onselect radio button update 2 input fields

Tags: javascript

i have 3 value like Amount, Name, and Duration

I have radio button list like this

```
<input id="p1" type="radio" name="select" value="25"> product1 $25 3week<br /> 
<input id="p2" type="radio" name="select" value="55"> product2 $55 4week<br /> 
<input id="p3" type="radio" name="select" value="75"> product3 $75 3week<br />
```

below this 3 input box there

```
<input id="t1" type="text" name="product" value=""> 
<input id="t2" type="text" name="price" value="">
<input id="t3" type="text" name="duration" value="">
```

i want if i select any option then below input fields should be filled with correspond value like this

```
<input id="t1" type="text" name="product" value="product1"> 
<input id="t2" type="text" name="price" value="$25">
<input id="t3" type="text" name="duration" value="3week">
```

Comment: Code you provided is of `checkbox` and in question heading you stated **onselect radio button..** . Why So Kolaveri?

Comment: i corrected it plz check now

Comment: **What have you tried so far?**

Comment: @NanaPartykar what does _"Kolaveri"_ mean?

Answer (score -1):

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/frayne_konok/5v7f9wys/), Try online now.

**HTML:**

```
<input id="p1" type="radio" name="select" value="25"> product1 $25 3week<br /> 
<input id="p2" type="radio" name="select" value="55"> product2 $55 4week<br /> 
<input id="p3" type="radio" name="select" value="75"> product3 $75 3week<br /> 

<input id="t1" type="text" name="product" value=""> 
<input id="t2" type="text" name="price" value="">
<input id="t3" type="text" name="duration" value="">
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function(){
  $("input[type=radio]").on("change", function(e){
    var getTxt = e.currentTarget.nextSibling.data;
    values = getTxt.split(" ");
    $("input[name=product]").val(values[1]);
    $("input[name=price]").val(values[2]);
    $("input[name=duration]").val(values[3]);
  })
})
```

Comment: You should not provide an answer to people who do not at least try an attempt to do their own work. You are not really helping them in this manner. Push for them to at least show an attempt.

Comment: can we do it without jquery

Comment: @Raj theres a website called Upwork or Freelancer. You should be able to find developers there to do the work for you for a small fee.